# Querying multiple database systems

Tags: sql, database

Is it possible to query (or better, join) data from two different database systems? Let's say I have postgresql and SQL Server and I want to join a table from postgres to a table in SQL Server?

It doesn't matter which programming language.

Comment: The only way that I can think of is to run your SQLCMD (or similar) or pipe out the results - then copy or type the results of you multiple SQL Output into one master file and the mail those results to your group..  Like you, I don't like the multiple e-mail results.

Comment: Knowing that this feature was called "Linked Tables" in MS-Access, I searched and I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639616/what-is-the-sql-server-equivalent-to-a-linked-table-in-ms-access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about utilizing a linked server? I use one to query an AS400 and join the results back to Microsoft SQL Server.

Quote from [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> Configure a linked server to enable the SQL Server Database Engine to
>   execute commands against OLE DB data sources outside of the instance
>   of SQL Server. Typically linked servers are configured to enable the
>   Database Engine to execute a Transact-SQL statement that includes
>   tables in another instance of SQL Server, or another database product
>   such as Oracle. Many types OLE DB data sources can be configured as
>   linked servers, including Microsoft Access and Excel. Linked servers
>   offer the following advantages:
>
> - The ability to access data from outside of SQL Server.
> - The ability to issue distributed queries, updates, commands, and transactions on heterogeneous data sources across the enterprise.
> - The ability to address diverse data sources similarly.